object detction model for a proto error is shown
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
'protoc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
i have try to install a object detction module using this git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git  after it when i install it i get the error in a importing proto
import tensorflow as tf
from object_detection.utils import config_util
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2
from google.protobuf import text_format


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The error arises because your shell is unable to find the protoc binary in the path. This is either because protoc has not been added to the path or because a protoc release has not been downloaded.
To resolve the error protoc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
follow these steps:

Download from the Protocol Buffers releases page.

Windows: Extract protoc-<version>-win64.zip, and add the directory containing protoc.exe to your system's PATH environment variable.

Linux: sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler

Mac: brew install protobuf


- Compile Protobufs:
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
- Set Up the Object Detection API:

git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
pip install tensorflow
pip install -r requirements.txt

Verify Installation:

python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py


This is how i solve issue when got similar error.

I use Linux and download protoc from Protocol Buffer releases too in order to ensure that I'm running a recent|current version. OS packages are convenient but often not as current (not as frequently updated).
